# Reshaping data with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

How would I reshape this kind of data? This is just a short exercpt of my data, the real dataset is much longer. So an automated solution for any kind of lengh would be very appreciated.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                   volume_1 = c(0.33, 0.58, 0.2),
                   name_1 = c("a", "b","c"),
                   volume_2 = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                   name_2 = c("x", "y", "z")
)
data

 id volume_1 name_1 volume_2 name_2
1  1     0.33      a      0.3      x
2  2     0.58      b      0.4      y
3  3     0.20      c      0.5      z
```

to this:

```
foo <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                  a = c(0.33, 0, 0),
                  b = c(0, 0.58, 0),
                  c = c(0, 0, 0.2),
                  x = c(0.3, 0, 0),
                  y = c(0, 0.4, 0),
                  z = c(0, 0, 0.5)
)
foo

 id    a    b   c   x   y   z
1  1 0.33 0.00 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0
2  2 0.00 0.58 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0
3  3 0.00 0.00 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.5
```

I´m aware of pivot_longer() or pivot_wider() and also of the reshape package, but I´m not sure how to accomplish this with any kind of length in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = starts_with('name'),values_from=starts_with('volume'),
              values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
     id volume_1_a_x volume_1_b_y volume_1_c_z volume_2_a_x volume_2_b_y volume_2_c_z
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1         0.33        0              0            0.3          0            0  
2     2         0           0.580          0            0            0.4          0  
3     3         0           0              0.2          0            0            0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a double `reshape`, clean names using `gsub`, and set `NA`s to zero.

```
r <- reshape(reshape(data, idvar="id", varying=list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5)), direction="long"),
             idvar="id", timevar="name_1", drop="time", direction="wide")
names(r) <- gsub("volume_1.", "", names(r))
r[is.na(r)] <- 0
r
#     id    a    b   c   x   y   z
# 1.1  1 0.33 0.00 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0
# 2.1  2 0.00 0.58 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0
# 3.1  3 0.00 0.00 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.5
```